# Numbered paragraphs

Tags: numbering, paragraphs

I would like to write something with numbered paragraphs - for those who know it the style should be the same of EGA. So instead of having something like

> blah blah
>
> Theorem 2.1
>
> blah blah
>
> Proof
>
> blah blah
>
> more content after the proof

I would like to have something like

> 2.1 blah blah
>
> 2.2 Theorem. blah blah
>
> 2.3 Proof. blah blah
>
> 2.4 more content after the proof

Is there a simple way to get this result?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of a [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/543208/219352) Also, if you can google the answer, you probably should do that.

Comment: Yes, I found that question, but the answers there did not seem very satisfying.

Comment: I think that's more to do with the fact that there are no genuinely satisfying solutions, rather than that StackOverflow is somehow deficient. (I think the lack of genuinely satsifying answers on this site too is evidence of this.) The point is, it's just a hard thing to do, given how LaTeX seems to abuse the paragraph hooks.

Comment: What if I want the numbering of paragraphs in brackets too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to number *all* paragraphs. I would do something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\swapnumbers

\newtheorem{num}{\unskip}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}[num]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{demo*}[num]{Proof}
\newenvironment{demo}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\begin{demo*}}
  {\popQED\end{demo*}}

\begin{document}
\section{Start}
\begin{num}
This is a numbered paragraph.

Actually it has two paragraphs.
\end{num}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{demo}
This is its proof.
\end{demo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually want to number every paragraph, but I will try your solution.

Comment: Your solutions works nicely. The only downside is that paragraphs introduced by \num have an additional dot after the number. I wonder whether that can be helped. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, I have solved even the last problem by customizing the theorem styles in amsthm and using one without the dot. :-D

Comment: Many thanks for being here to give us hands! I shared this post.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use the `everyhook` package for this. It numbers section names due to the way they are handled, but there is probably a way around that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[excludeor]{everyhook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{paragraphs}[section]
\begin{document}
\PushPostHook{par}{%
        \stepcounter{paragraphs}%
        \llap{\thesection.\theparagraphs\ \kern\parindent}%
}
\section{Foo}
\lipsum
\section{Bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but it creates some problems when theorem-like environments are used. Thank you anyway. :-)